# confusion about classes, objects and methods python

Tags: python, class, oop, object, attributes

I am trying to figure out why 'v3' below doesn't work and raises an attribute error. What makes v1 and v2 work and not v3? The code is short and reproducible, and I think it is also simple enough to not need explanation but pls let me know if anything is not clear.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, ts_df):
        self.all_df = ts_df

    def simple_av(self, lookback=""):
        self.agg = self.all_df.mean(axis=1)

class Example_two(object):
    def __init__(self, ts_df, method):
        self.ts = ts_df
        self.method = method

    def apply_method(self, **kwargs):
        self.output = self.method(self.ts, **kwargs)

ts = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2))

'''v1'''
ex = Example(ts)
ex.simple_av()
print (ex.agg.head())

'''v2'''
func = pd.rolling_mean
ex = Example_two( ts, func)
req_args = dict({'window': 3})
ex.apply_method(**req_args)
print (ex.output.head())

'''v3'''
func = Example.simple_av
ex= Example(ts)
ex.func()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third example fails because `func` exists but `ex.func` does not. `ex.func` looks up `"func"` in the attributes of `Example` class and fails.

You could call `func` in procedural style, passing `ex` as first argument:

```
func(ex)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
ex.simple_av()
```

(the 2 first examples use a call to a defined method, so it works)